# In a German environment and working with Python 3.x - how can I preserve umlauts while converting ASCII characters to upper case?

Tags: case, diacritics

In a German environment and working with Python 3.x - how can I preserve umlauts while converting ASCII characters to upper case? `"Öfter TUT Übermut SELTEN gut".lower()` yields `"öfter tut übermut selten gut"`. However, I want to keep the 'Ö' and the 'Ü'.

Comment: Do you mean preserve the first letter of the sentence capital? Try `"Übermut Tut SELTEN gut".capitalize()`, yields 'Übermut tut selten gut'

Comment: No, I want a str.lower() and str.upper() purely for ASCII characters. I can create a dictionary but that seems not very efficient to me. So, maybe, there is a more elegant way.

Comment: I see - in this case `capitalize()` seems to return the correct thing by coincidence, can you add a better example? (I am sure answer is somewhere in `ord()` :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be better (more efficient) solutions but what about:

```
s = "Öfter TUT Übermut SELTEN gut"

def lower_ascii(sentence):
    res = []
    for char in sentence:
        if ord(char) <= 122:  # 122 == z
            res.append(char.lower())
        else:
            res.append(char)
    
    return ''.join(res)


print(lower_ascii(s))
```

Output:

```
Öfter tut Übermut selten gut
```

Explanation:

- `ord()` gives you the value of that character as int (unicode). Read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord)
- Ascii `z` is 122 and the higher value between [a-z] and [A-Z] (check it with `ord('z')`)
- So what I do is convert anything that is lower than `z` (since all umlauts have higher values) leaving the rest as-is
- Using a list to store each character and combine it back into a string instead of appending on a new string because of `str` being immutable (should be "faster" and require less space)

You can use the same loop to do anything you need in ascii/non-ascii chars